# How to change a instance in a set

Tags: java

I have the following Set, I would like to replace any instance that is multiple of 10 by the string "10". Can anyone guide me in the right direction please.

```
Set<Integer> set3 = new HashSet<Integer>();

       for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
           Random ran = new Random();
            number = 1+ran.nextInt(1000);
          set3.add(number);
       }
```

Comment: You can't add a `String` in `Set<Integer` then what is the meaning of replacing it in the same `Set`? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's a set of `Integer`s, you can't add a `String` to it.

Comment: You guys are totally right, but i was required to create a set of integers numbers and then replace any instance  multiple of 10 by its string value

Comment: Maybe the requirement is, that you should iterate through your `Set` and if a number is a multiple of 10, you should print out "10"?

Comment: or to replace the multiple of 10 by 10 itself! so you could work with modulo!

Comment: Thats what I thought, but I need to replace it by the correspondent string

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ReplaceIntegers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> set3 = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Object> objectSet = new HashSet<>();

        Random generator = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            set3.add(1+generator.nextInt(1000));
        }

        set3.stream()
                .filter(n -> n%10 == 0)
                .forEach(n -> objectSet.add(n.toString()));

        objectSet.stream()
               .forEach(v -> System.out.println(v));

        for(Integer i : set3) {
            if(i%10 == 0) 
                System.out.println(i + " is a multiple of 10");
            else
                System.out.println("Number: " + i);
        }
    }

}
```

Patrick

Comment: @user3648429 see my edit, i updated the code, now every %10 Value will be added to the Set<Object> and after this, the ojectSet will be printed out.

Comment: @user3648429 Notice: you need to use Java8, otherwise the Stream API wont work.

Comment: i followed your logic but I did it slightly different. Sets doesn't allows duplicates. Lets say instead of objectSet.add(n.toString())) I want to do objectSet.add("ten")) to let the user know that those numbers are multiples of ten. How would you allow such duplication?

Answer (score 1):

The output is going to be a mixed set of integers and strings, so the method signature you're writing is going to look like:

```
Set<Object> foo(Set<Integer> input);
```

First let's write the algorithm the easy way, in Scala, then we'll convert it to Java. You want to change each item in the collection, so that's a `map` operation.

```
def foo(s: Set[Int]): Set[Any] = s map { i => if (i % 10 == 0) "10" else i }
```

In Java 8, it's similar, but you have to convert the `Set` to a `Stream` to do the mapping, and then back to a `Set` again.

```
static Set<Object> foo(Set<Integer> s) {
    return s.stream()
        .map(i -> i % 10 == 0 ? "10" : i)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

If you want to go back to Java 7, you don't even have streams, or lambdas to make defining the map operation feasible, so you just have to understand how `map` is defined and then implement it procedurally in your code.

```
static Set<Object> foo(Set<Integer> s) {
    Set<Object> result = new HashSet<>();
    for (Integer i : s) {
        result.add(i % 10 == 0 ? "10" : i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The Java 5-6 solution is almost the same, just without the diamond syntax:

```
static Set<Object> foo(Set<Integer> s) {
    Set<Object> result = new HashSet<Object>();
    for (Integer i : s) {
        result.add(i % 10 == 0 ? "10" : i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And in Java 3-4 you lose the for loop, autounboxing, and generics...

```
static Set foo(Set s) {
    Set result = new HashSet();
    Iterator it = s.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Integer i = (Integer) it.next();
        Object o = i;
        if (i.intValue() % 10 == 0) o = "10";
        result.add(o);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Integer> set3 = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<Object> set4 = new HashSet<Object>();

       for(Integer integer: set3){
          if(integer%10==0){
              set4.add(integer.toString());    
          } else {
              set4.add(integer);
          }
       };
set3=set4;
```

You are unable to put `String` into `Set<Integer>`, you should decrease the specificity of the type to the closest common parent class of both `String` and `Integer` - `Object`. In addition, I would strongly discourage using "replace" (remove+add) on a `Set` you are iterating through: this can lead to potential problems with data consistency. Just copy your elements in another `Set` and then replace the original one.